# Google Apps SMTP issue on 1and1

Tags: wordpress, smtp, gmail, contact-form-7

I am at my wits end here. I'm trying to set up SMTP settings for use in Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7. My email server is set up through Google Apps and my website is hosted on 1and1. I am using WP plugin Configure SMTP to set it up. After I try to send test email, I get the following error:

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

My SMTP settings are:

```
SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 465
Secure connection: SSL
Auth: yes
SMTP username: my-username@my-domain.com
SMTP password: password
Sender email: my-username@my-domain.com
```

I have also tried port 587 on TLS and port 25. I have called 1and1 two times, both times they said they don't block ports and cannot help me since my email is pointed to Gmail. I have tried other WP plugins to set up the SMTP settings. I have doublechecked that the MX records that Google supplied me correct in my 1and1 DNS. I have no idea what else I can do, I have read that other have a similar problem with this set up and with others, yet I have not found anything that has solved my issue. Many are saying it is the webhost that is blocking the ports yet 1and1 said both times I called that they don't block ports and it is a Gmail problem. I don't know what else to try.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

They are not being honest they do block SMTP ports 465 and 587 
If you have Domain hosted at 1and1 and configure an email address they miay say they do block..
I have wordpress site attempting to use Contact for 7 and POSTMAN SMTP plugins
Postman has diag routine, it clearly shows that 1and1 are blocking the only mail port open is 443.

Comment: I was told by 1and1 today that they block SMTP other than their own.